# Flutter: Get name and line of file that caused exception using runZonedGuarded

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I'm catching exceptions with runZonedGuarded as the [documentation specifies](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors#errors-not-caught-by-flutter) and sending them to me via API

However, in the runZonedGuarded parameters, only the object containing the text that caused the exception is returned and I would also like to know which file and which line caused the returned exception, is it possible?

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
     runZonedGuarded(() {
     runApp(MyApp());
   }, (Object error, StackTrace stack) {
     print(error);
   });
}
```

Output example:

> "NoSuchMethodError: (...)"

Example output I would like to receive:

> "package:project/lib/main.dart:4 - NoSuchMethodError: (...)"

How can I get this information (filename and line) from my caught exception?

Comment: you have `StackTrace stack` for that

Comment: @pskink I really hadn't noticed everything that is brought on the stack, it worked, thank's!

Comment: your welcome, note that stack traces can be parsed with https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace package, that parses stack trace into a list of frames - this is done with `Trace.from` method